# Complex Task, LAG and RETAIN functions may not be good enough

Tags: sas

Probably the most complicated task I encountered.
Could really use your help here...

Let's say I have a data set similar to  this:

```
data have;
rk = 1;
version = 0;
treatment_ind = 1;
start_date_1 = "01jan2013"d;
end_date_1 = "01feb2013"d;
start_date_2 = "21jan2013"d;
end_date_2 = "18feb2013"d;
money_field = 32;
OUTPUT;

rk = 1;
version = 1;
treatment_ind = 1;
start_date_1 = "01feb2013"d;
end_date_1 = "01apr2013"d;
start_date_2 = "3jan2013"d;
end_date_2 = "9feb2013"d;
money_field = 1;
OUTPUT;

rk = 1;
version = 2; 
treatment_ind = 2;
start_date_1 = "01jan2013"d;
end_date_1 = "01feb2013"d;
start_date_2 = "21jan2013"d;
end_date_2 = "18feb2013"d;
money_field = 65;
OUTPUT;

rk = 1;
version = 3;
treatment_ind = 3;
start_date_1 = "01jan2013"d;
end_date_1 = "01jun2013"d;
start_date_2 = "21jul2013"d;
end_date_2 = "18aug2013"d;
money_field = 6;
OUTPUT;

rk = 1;
version = 0;
treatment_ind = 7;
start_date_1 = "11mar2013"d;
end_date_1 = "22may2013"d;
start_date_2 = "21feb2013"d;
end_date_2 = "24feb2013"d;
money_field = 34;
OUTPUT;



FORMAT start_date_1 end_date_1 start_date_2 end_date_2 DATE9.;
run;
```

if treatment_ind = 1  - That's an easy one. A regular case, All calculations work just fine  for me.

The trickier ones are below:

If treatment_ind = 2,
I need to do few things:

1. First of all, the easier task: to update few fields in existing rows (where treatment_ind = 2)
2. Every rk owns somewhere a treatment_ind = 2, should act in certain way.

If treatment_ind = 3,

1. First of all, the easier task: to update few fields in existing rows (where treatment_ind = 3)
2. Every rk owns somewhere a treatment_ind = 3, should act in certain way. Different way.

And so on....
I have 8 different indicators that act in different ways, not just for the current row, 
but EVERY row , by RK, owns the indicator somewhere...

Some of them actually cancels behaviors of other indicators.
For example, 
if a certain RK has somewhere an Indicator_ind = 7,
than treatment_ind = 3 should not be calculated.

When all of this is done,
I should use Retain in order to accumulate numbers from one row to another...

Main problem is,
I can't upload the table I work with to explain better the situation I'm facing,
and the Data Set I did upload is REALLY simple and do not represent the complexity of that task...

If for example,
indicator_ind = 1 , then difference between dates should be according to first set of dates.
In other indicator it should be calculated according to the second set.

The same goes to lots and lots of other calculations...

I know it would be probably tough to answer this...

But, for a start, I'm asking for a direction...
as Retain/Lag  alone won't help me, I'm afraid...

Comment: Next time please don't put CAPS-LOCK on the whole title. It would be clearer if you can upload at least a sample of your data set. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

This might help you with your problem, but since I can't see your data set it's hard to predict. You can play around with the RETURN and SELECT statements. RETURN skips the current data step iteration and moves on to the next iteration. SELECT works like a "switch" statement in other programming languages. Once a condition is fulfilled, it will only execute that condition's consequent statement.

```
data work.test;
set work.sample;
if indicator_ind=7 and treatment_ind=3 then return;



select; 
    when(treatment_ind = 1 and version = 0) do;

    rk = 1;
    start_date_1 = "01jan2013"d;
    end_date_1 = "01feb2013"d;
    start_date_2 = "21jan2013"d;
    end_date_2 = "18feb2013"d;
    money_field = 32;
    OUTPUT;
    end;

    when(treatment_ind = 1 and version = 1) do;

    rk = 1;
    start_date_1 = "01feb2013"d;
    end_date_1 = "01apr2013"d;
    start_date_2 = "3jan2013"d;
    end_date_2 = "9feb2013"d;
    money_field = 1;
    OUTPUT;
    end;

    when(treatment_ind = 2 and version = 2) do;

    rk = 1;
    start_date_1 = "01jan2013"d;
    end_date_1 = "01feb2013"d;
    start_date_2 = "21jan2013"d;
    end_date_2 = "18feb2013"d;
    money_field = 65;
    OUTPUT;
    end; 


    when(treatment_ind = 3 and version = 3) do;

    rk = 1;
    start_date_1 = "01jan2013"d;
    end_date_1 = "01jun2013"d;
    start_date_2 = "21jul2013"d;
    end_date_2 = "18aug2013"d;
    money_field = 6;
    OUTPUT;
    end;

    when(treatment_ind = 7 and version = 0) do;

    rk = 1;
    start_date_1 = "11mar2013"d;
    end_date_1 = "22may2013"d;
    start_date_2 = "21feb2013"d;
    end_date_2 = "24feb2013"d;
    money_field = 34;
    OUTPUT;
    end;

    otherwise;
end;

FORMAT start_date_1 end_date_1 start_date_2 end_date_2 DATE9.;
run;
```